# How to count "visible" tabs in jquery?

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, jquery-ui-tabs, jquery-tabs

I inherited this code and now need to make modifications.  I have a series of tabs:

```
<div id="Tabs">
    <ul>
        <li><a href="#divGen" id="lnkGeneral">General</a></li>
        <li><a href="#divA" id="lnkA">A</a></li>
        <li><a href="#divB" id="lnkB">B</a></li>
        <li><a href="#divC" id="lnkC">C</a></li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

These are hidden/shown using jquery depending on the value selected from a dropdown:

```
$("#divA").hide(); $("#divB").show(); $("#divC").hide();  
$("#lnkA").hide(); $("#lnkB").show(); $("#lnkC").hide();
```

The first tab (divGen) is always displayed.  I need a way to loop through the list of tabs to determine which tabs may be visible, as I am adding a button to go to the next tab.  Because the tabs are visible on a dynamic basis I need to determine both if the button should be shown and which tab to ‘rotate’ to when pressed.  I have tried the following with no luck:

```
var $tabs = $('#Tabs').tabs();  
var i, count = 0;  
for (i = 0; i < $tabs.tabs('length'); i++) {  
    if ($tabs.tabs(i).is('visible')) {  
        count++;  
    }  
}  

if (count > 1)) {  
    Display the button.  
}
```

What am I missing?  I have looked at all the examples and cannot find a solution.  I have an idea it is due to the hide/show and not doing the visible test correctly.

Thank You in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For the button show/hide:

```
// if more than one tab is visible display the button  
if ($('#Tabs ul li a:visible').length > 1)) {  
       //Display the button.  
} else {  
       //Display the button.  
}
```

The function the button invokes is:

```
function fnNextTab(div) {  
    var $tabs = $(div).tabs();
    var selected = $tabs.tabs('option', 'selected');
    var max = $tabs.tabs('length') - 1; // Zero based

    $(div + ' ul li a').each(function(i) {
        // if the tab is visible and 'after' the current tab select it
        if (($(this).is(':visible')) && (i > selected)) {
            $tabs.tabs("select", i);    // This selects the tab
            $tabs.tabs('load', i);      // This displays the tab
            return false;               // Done searching
        }

        if (i >= max) {
            // Goto the General (first) tab
            $tabs.tabs("select", 0);    // This selects the tab
            $tabs.tabs('load', 0);      // This displays the tab
        }
    });
}
```

'div' is passed in on the call, so that this function can be used by different pages; each having a different collection of tabs, as well as being different names.

Answer (score 4):

[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/mNz55/2/)

```
if ( $('#Tabs ul li:visible').length > 1) ) {  
    //Display the button.  
}
```

**Update**

If you're hiding the anchor tag (which it seems you are) you may need to use

```
if ( $('#Tabs ul li a:visible').length > 1) ) {  
    //Display the button.  
}
```

Comment: For some reason this returned a count of ALL the tabs, including the "hidden" ones.  It also does not address the second need for the loop, which is to let me identify the next visible tab so I can switch to it.

Comment: Identify the next visible tab? You can do that with this code as well, although I don't see anything pertaining to that in your original code. I only see you keeping a counter variable and acting upon it's total.

Comment: Oh, and as to why your items are not being counted properly, put the `id` in the `<li>` instead of the `<a>`. It doesn't make sense to hide the inner link and not the entire tab. Either that or change my selector to `if ( $('#Tabs ul li a:visible').length > 1) ) {`. See update

Comment: The HTML was setup this way when I got it, as to changeing it I would have to go through the entire site and hope I found them all.  What I'm trying to do is a simple self adjusting mod that will show/hide a button.  The other is a function the button will call to move from one tab to the next.  I only showed the button code as that was the first problem and making the loop work in that would give me the code to select the next tab.  The logic for the function will go something like this:  for (i="current tab" ; ...) { if ('visible') { 'activate tab'; return; } } 'activate tab 0'

Comment: Your answer is a much cleaner way for me to do the button and I will use it for that.  I have the code to get the current selected tab and activating the new tab.  I just need how to loop through the tabs and test each one for visibility.